# Automapper - How to implement a lookup

Tags: c#, automapper

I have some legacy code. This code maps one Address type to another. For example, I have a statement that looks like this:

```
CreateMap<SourceAddress, DestinationAddress>()
  .ForMember(a => a.State, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.State.Name));
```

The above code works. However, the underlying API (i.e. `SourceAddress`) has changed. In updated API, the `State` property no longer exists. Instead, there is a `StateId` property. However, I still need to map the state name to the property in `DestinationAddress`.

My question is, is there a way to implement a lookup in a mapping statement in AutoMapper?

Update: included original `SourceAddress` model, updated `SourceAddress` model, and `DestinationAddress` model

```
SourceAddress (original)
------------------------
Id
State (object)
City (string)

SourceAddress (modified)
------------------------
Id
StateId (int)
City (string)

DestinationAddress
------------------
Id
State (string)
City (string)
```

My goal is to map the name of the state from the `SourceAddress` object to the `State` property in the `DestinationAddress` object. Somehow, I need to do a lookup using the `StateId` value (i.e., get the name of the state from the State object, based on the StateId value).

Comment: What do you mean by "lookup"? It's unclear where the data should come from now that the source no longer contains it.

Comment: @Xerillio I just updated the question to show the models. Effectively, I need to lookup the "State" object using the `StateId` value first. Once I have the `State` object, I need to get the name from the State object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a converter.
The List of state can be retrived with dependency injection, because they don't change very often and you don't select this list from database everytime.

```
public class Converter : ITypeConverter<SourceAddress, DestinationAddress>
{
    private readonly IList<State> _states;

    public Converter (IList<State> states)
    {        
        _states = states;
    }
    public DestinationAddress Convert(SourceAddress source, DestinationAddress destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.State = _states.Single(x => x.Id == source.StateId).Name;
        return destination;
    }
}
```

and create the mapping using the converter

```
CreateMap<SourceAddress, DestinationAddress>()
  .ForMember(a => a.State, opt => opt.MapFrom<Converter>());
```

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html